# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n^{\,3}=\infty\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Let $z_n$ be a complex sequence.

How would I go about proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n^{\,3}=\infty\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$?

Is there a formal way to prove divergence other than the fact it contradicts the definition of convergence?

Comment: A sequence can be neither convergent nor divergent.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n|=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For a complex sequence $\{z_n \}$,

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} z_n = \infty$$ means that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \vert z_n \vert = \infty$.

As the real maps $x \mapsto x^3$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ as well as $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$, the required equivalence is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $|z_n^3|=|z_n|^3\ge M$, then $|z_n|>\lfloor\sqrt[3]M\rfloor$, and conversely if $|z_n|\ge M$, then $|z_n^3|=|z_n|^3>M^3$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: ouch, I didn't see complex. But the fix is easy.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean for $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$?

Well, for any open neighborhood of $\infty$ all terms of the sequence are eventually contained in it. So we have, given any $R>0$, we define the open set $U_R=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>R\}$ and we know that there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $z_k\in U_R$ for every $k\geq N_0$.  What does the cubing operation in $\mathbb{C}$ do to modulus? This gives one direction.  For the other you can argue in a similar way but one needs to be mindful of multivaluedness of the cube root.